# how to use functions of wordpress in custom php file

Tags: wordpress, function

i use function  ***have_posts()***  in custom php file that includes wp-load.php.
but i have this error :

Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\khanehkheshti\wp-includes\query.php on line 767

php file :

```
require_once( wp_normalize_path(ABSPATH).'wp-load.php');

public static function home() {


    $query = new WP_Query(array(category_name => "img_news", 'posts_per_page' => '3' ));
    $home = array();
    $in = array();


    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $home['title']  = get_the_title();
        $home['content']  = get_the_content();
        $home['img']  = the_post_thumbnail( array( 300, 260 ) );
        $in[] = $home;
    }

    echo JSON_encode($in);


    return $in;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the WordPress in your custom PHP file. You can use following code to initialize it.

```
/**
 *  WordPress initializing
 */
function find_wordpress_base_path()
{
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

    do
    {
        if(file_exists($dir.'/wp-config.php')) return $dir;
    }
    while($dir = realpath($dir.'/..'));

    return NULL;
}

define('BASE_PATH', find_wordpress_base_path().'/');
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require(BASE_PATH.'wp-load.php');

// Now you have access to WordPress functions here
```

Comment: Don't you have any other error on the file? the $query line should have a syntax error. Change it to `$query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => 'img_news', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ));`

Comment: use this code but not work : `<?php
function find_wordpress_base_path()
{
 $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

 do
 {
  if(file_exists($dir.'/wp-config.php')) return $dir;
 }
 while($dir = realpath($dir.'/..'));

 return NULL;
}

define('BASE_PATH', find_wordpress_base_path().'/');
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require(BASE_PATH.'wp-load.php');


while (have_posts()){
 the_post();

 echo the_title();
}


?>`

Comment: You should initialize the `$query` variable and then use it to check if it has posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the wp-load.php with wp-blog-header.php. Here is the sample code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('PATHHERE/wp-blog-header.php'); 

public static function home() {
    $query = new WP_Query(array(category_name => "img_news", 'posts_per_page' => '3' ));
    $home = array();
    $in = array();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $home['title']  = get_the_title();
        $home['content']  = get_the_content();
        $home['img']  = the_post_thumbnail( array( 300, 260 ) );
        $in[] = $home;
    }

    echo JSON_encode($in);

    return $in;

}
```